# Player won't detect collision when enemies get close

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

I've managed to make contact between the bullets and enemies but for some reason the main character won't make contact with the enemies.

```
    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    var firstBody:SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody:SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & Bullet) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & Enemy) != 0{

        bulletDidCollideWithEnemy(bulletNode: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Zombie: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

    }else{
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask & Player) != 0 && (secondBody.categoryBitMask & Enemy) != 0{

        playerCollideWithEnemy(playerNode: firstBody.node as! SKSpriteNode, Zombie: secondBody.node as! SKSpriteNode)

        }

}
```

Comment: Put a break point in this method and see what is wrong when contact happens.

Comment: is player categoryBitMask < enemy categoryBitMask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is having this same problem as I did, here is the solution to the problem. I just had to make sure that "Enemy" was visible to other objects. Huge importance! Hope this helps somebody out.

```
Enemy.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
Enemy.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
```